# High performance Springboot Banking Application Design

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns

I was trying to do a project involving multi-threading in springboot.

In the Bank Application , I can make operations like `doWithdrawal()` as `synchronized`in order to maintain the integrity of the account , but I am not able to figure out how to do it at particular account level only .

Since users with different account numbers should be able perform withdrawal at same time , with my current code `doWithdrawal()` will make all operations synchronized irrespective of the account number .

Currently I have very basic functionality below where i have used on withdrawals from **one account** as a `synchronized` operation . I want a scenario where **different account holders can withdraw from there own account at same time** , but while multiple withdraws from the same account at same time , only that process should be synchronous .

So what I am looking here for is how the application should be designed to have such functionality , I am aware we can use `@Async` for asynchronous operations but not sure how will that fit in the scenario where withdrawal for same account should be synchronous but different should be asynchronous.

`Account.java`

```
public class Account {

    int number ;
    float currentBalance ;
    float openingBalance ;
    String accountHolder ;
    String branch ;
    float rateOfInterest ;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public float getCurrentBalance() {
        return currentBalance;
    }
    public void setCurrentBalance(float currentBalance) {
        this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
    }
    public float getOpeningBalance() {
        return openingBalance;
    }
    public void setOpeningBalance(float openingBalance) {
        this.openingBalance = openingBalance;
    }
    public String getAccountHolder() {
        return accountHolder;
    }
    public void setAccountHolder(String accountHolder) {
        this.accountHolder = accountHolder;
    }
    public String getBranch() {
        return branch;
    }
    public void setBranch(String branch) {
        this.branch = branch;
    }
    public float getRateOfInterest() {
        return rateOfInterest;
    }
    public void setRateOfInterest(float rateOfInterest) {
        this.rateOfInterest = rateOfInterest;
    }


}
```

`App.java`

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BankService.openAccount(1001);

        Thread2 t2 = new Thread2();
        Thread3 t3 = new Thread3();
        Thread4 t4 = new Thread4();

        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();

    }
}

class Thread2 extends Thread {
    BankService bs = BankService.getInstance();
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("bs instrance is"+bs.hashCode());
        bs.doWithdrawal(200, 1001);
    }
}
class Thread3 extends Thread {
    BankService bs = BankService.getInstance();

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("bs instrance is"+bs.hashCode());

        bs.doWithdrawal(100, 1001);
    }
}
class Thread4 extends Thread {
    BankService bs = BankService.getInstance();
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("bs instrance is"+bs.hashCode());

        bs.doWithdrawal(100, 1001);
    }
}
```

`BankService.java`

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;



public class BankService {


    private static BankService bankService ;

    private BankService(){

    }

    public static BankService getInstance(){

        if(bankService==null){
            return bankService = new BankService();
        }

        return bankService;
    }


    static Map<Integer,Account> accountMap = new HashMap<Integer, Account>();

    public void doDeposit(float amount,int accountNum){

        Account acc = accountMap.get(accountNum);
        acc.setCurrentBalance(acc.getCurrentBalance()+amount);
        System.out.println("made deposit");
        System.out.println("account :   "+acc.getNumber()+"   "+acc.getCurrentBalance());

    }


    public synchronized void doWithdrawal(float amount,int accountNum){

        Account acc = accountMap.get(accountNum);
        acc.setCurrentBalance(acc.getCurrentBalance()-amount);
        System.out.println("account :   "+acc.getNumber()+"   "+acc.getCurrentBalance());

    }

    public void checkBalance(int accountNumber){

    }

    public static void openAccount(int accnum){

        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.setCurrentBalance(2000);
        acc.setNumber(1001);

        accountMap.put(acc.getNumber(), acc);

        System.out.println("obj is"+accountMap);

    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying very hard to work around spring... Using things like `getInstance()` is quite a sure sign you rre doing the wrong things in a spring application. Don't synchronize the method instead synchronize on the `Account`. You also might want to use a concurrent save implementation of the `Map`.

Comment: thanks for your input , i actually was just working with singleton pattern practice as well so that's why i used this behavior , i know we could use `@Component` to make it a bean and inject it's dependency instead . correct me if i'm wrong .

Comment: @M.Deinum also in case of a more real time scenario , do you think having transaction managed database would be better than using a concurrent hashmap ?

Comment: Ofcourse it would especially if you have multiple instances of an application your current situation wouldn't even work.

Comment: @M.Deinum so i believe something like this should work  ? have `@Async` on the `doWithdrawal()` (to support multiple threads/accounts to execute ) and `synchronized` on the particular account object inside that method . This way i would get asynchronous behavior and integrated accounts as well .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of synchronizing on the entire method, you can synchronize on that particular 'accountNum' as follows :

```
 public void doWithdrawal(int accNum) {
    synchronized(accountMap.get(accNum)) {
        // now perform withdrawal
    }
 }
```

This way you will be synchronizing only when the account number is the same.